# Client-side Validation working but still receiving spam

Tags: jquery, html, validation, email

I have implemented a jQuery client-side validation on my contact form after receiving multiple spam emails. After ensuring the validation works correctly, I am still receiving the spam emails. Somehow the fields do not meet the validation rules I set, yet are still going through. For example, I am testing for a valid email address, but the form allows a number "1" to be used in the email field. I investigated the Google Analytics and it doesn't appear a user was even on the Contact Page at the time the emails are being sent. Can anyone offer any explanation? I would like to avoid back-end validation, if possible.

Comment: can you link to the form ?

Comment: It sounds like someone has copied and pasted your form to another address, and is using your `<form action` method to send data to your inbox.  You would need server-side validation to stop this.

Comment: @Godisgood thank you for this information. I guess I will have to go with server-side validation after all...

Comment: @JayD here's the link: http://pup-grass.com/contact.html

Comment: @Godisgood there wouldn't be a way to find out what address is using my form, would there?

Comment: Server-side that could be possible . . . what address are you recieving the mail from?

Comment: jQuery Validation is JavaScript... anyone can simply disable their JavaScript.  If you want bullet-proof validation you must also use a server-side technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple : you "would like to avoid back-end validation, if possible", but it's not possible to defeat spam only by a client side validation.

As you said it, a part of your spam comes from clients that don't appear in Google Analytics, which is likely to mean client not running javascript.

Although it is theoretically possible with a scripted headless browser, most spam is sended through non browser software, running in botnets (zombie PCs). The spam software just sends lot of HTTP POST requests to your server. This kind of sofware just doesn't execute your javascript and jquery code.

Client side code may help to defeat spam, but **there should be always some kind of server-side filtering**.

Comment: 'some kind' is being generous. If you use client side validation u should have as MUCH validation in the backend

Comment: @Darkbee : Of course, yes! It depends a lot of how much is expected from the anti-spam, and how targeted is the form. And obviously of already available solutions used...